# Android Studio KMM iOS run will not start in iPhone Simulator

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am following the "Create your first multiplatform application" tutorial from [KotlinLang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html) and everything worked fine until I try to run the example on an iOS machine. The device simulator opens after a long time but the app is not run on it. I tried starting the simulator first and then making the test with the same results. I tried iPhone 11 and iPhone 8 simulators all with the same result. Everything compiles and builds successfully but no application shows up on the screen in the simulator.

[image: Stimulator run iPhone 8]

I can run the iOS test and the result is successful as you can see with the iPhone 11 test but still the app will not show in the simulator. I also tried the KMM-Sample-Master from Github with the same results.

[image: iPhone 11 test]

Can anyone help with this? If you need more information then please request it?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: [Xcode error after switching between device and simulator: Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework was built for iOS Simulator.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40907?_ga=2.168680161.1112605415.1606965023-1197419709.1606965022)

Comment: If you open the iOS application with Xcode and you run it from there, you are able to launch the applicatoin on the simulator?

Comment: I never encounter this problem, but this there are reletated youtrack issue regarding this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=Timeout%20while%20waiting%20for%20simulated%20application%20PID

Comment: Hello, @BroPage! This seems to be a bug. Please consider reporting it at the kotl.in/issue(short link to the official https://youtrack.jetbrains.com). While there are similar issues about AppCode, I can't find any cases related to AS KMM Plugin which you're using here.

Comment: Thanks @ArtyomDegtyarev I have opened this bug report with JetBrains [link] (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-654).

Comment: Thanks @shadowsheep, This is a good workaround. The iOS application does run in the Xcode IDE. However the whole idea of KMM was to be a 1 IDE solution for multiplatform development I thought. For that reason I am going to continue to search for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Mine was not properly a workaround, but a way to check if xcode build tools and simulator were okay. I'll follow your issue now, 'cause I'm curious ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I cannot run the iosApp from Android Studio while the Android App runs correctly.
What I did is building the iosApp via Android Studio. So in the list of run configurations, select iosApp and then click Run.
Once the build is finished open Xcode, select the iosApp, and run the project from there.
Every time there are changes in the code, build it in Android Studio and run it from Xcode.

Comment: Please verify that you are running the latest Android Studio Build on the Stable Update Cannel. It has worked for me since the update to build specified above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was connected with permissions. To resolve I ran:

`sudo chown username ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Solution was found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-21779)

Answer (score -1):

As of Android Studio 4.1.2 This issue has been corrected. Build stamp follows:

```
Android Studio 4.1.2
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882, built on December 19, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.16
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, com.intellij.marketplace, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.squareup.sqldelight, org.moe.community, com.jetbrains.kmm
```

Comment: Is that relevant to the question? How does it help to start android studio?

Comment: Screen Shot of Android Studio Launching the iOS simulator. On a iOS system of course.